# PHP CURL: Instagram returns empty string to remote server

Tags: php, curl, instagram

I found out that I can get latest user posts in JSON format with a simple CURL request to

https://www.instagram.com/some_nickname/?__a=1

So I am trying:

```
$url = 'https://www.instagram.com/some_nickname/?__a=1';

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

The code works fine on my local machine and returns a JSON array, from which I get the latest posts of a user. The problem is that the very same code returns empty string from any of my remote servers (I've tried 3 different web-hosting providers).

Please, advice.

Answer (score 1):

Instagram blocked the ranges of IP hostings. I have seen the following information:

> Instagram has started applying extremely restrictive limits to
> requests from IPs that are detected as cloud servers.
>
> A couple of requests will go through at first, but after a moment, all
> requests will be blocked, with a very long timer until they are
> unblocked again. After this timer, you get a couple more requests, and
> the cycle repeats.
>
> Since websites must be hosted in the cloud, any interaction with
> Instagram becomes extremely difficult if the cloud provider is on
> Instagram's block list. All the cloud providers I've tried are on that
> list.

You need to use proxy. But it will be a difficult task, because many proxy(in my experience) are also blocked

Comment: So, what is it all about? Is it done to disable people to use the API or something? Why do they have it then?